# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Drupal's [second moderator election](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Clive] [image: MPD]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/election/2).

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators !!

Answer (score 12):

Bwa-ha-ha-ha.  Bwa-ha-ha-ha!  BWA-HA-HA-HA-HA!  YOU ALL WILL TREMBLE AT MY MIGHTY POWERS!

Seriously, thanks for the votes.  I will do my best to be a voice of the community and not exert my will over the site.  If I do something that you don't agree with, please call me out in Meta.DA so we (as in the community) can discuss what happened.

I will have somewhat limited access over the next day or two, as I am in Philadelphia, PA, USA, and we are dealing with getting back to normal after Hurricane Sandy.

Comment: Heh heh I was just typing out a very similar evil cackle when this popped up ;) Congrats mate

Comment: Congratulations! (Aside: *fistbump of solidarity* Stay safe and dry!)

Comment: Congratulations MPD, hope you get recover from the trouble of Hurricane Sandy soon..

Comment: Congrats MPD :)

Answer (score 11):

Congratulations to both MPD and Clive!  I'm positive that you guys will do a stellar job!

It feels pretty rubbish to come in third place out of three people though ;)

Congrats :)

Answer (score 10):

Just to echo what MPD said, thanks to everyone that voted and I'll be trying to conduct myself in the same way he's laid out.

If you've ever got an issue with something I do, just add a post to the meta site and we'll get it sorted out in a nice friendly way.

Also commiserations to Chapabu, a thoroughly worthy opponent. Next time dude :)

Comment: Congratulations Clive !!!

Comment: Congrats Clive :)

Comment: congrats Clive...keep the good work...you were my first choice :)

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations to the new moderators - looking forward to working with you.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to working with you too :)

Answer (score 1):

Congratulation to Clive and MPD. Hope this community will improve more better with positive guys like you.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations to both candidates..I was impressed with your profiles and dedication to Drupal. It was hard to choose.